# Vectors in Arrays

Tags: c++

If I have an array of vectors, will the vector be limited in its resizing ability due to the contiguous storage nature of arrays?

Comment: It will not. The vectors can resize to accommodate more space, but the array can only hold a maximum amount of vector containers.

Comment: In a word, No. The memory the vector works with isn't a part of the array.

Comment: No, as everyone has answered so far, but you don't need to have an array of vectors, you could have a vector of vectors: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: @Collin, Or an "array" of vectors: `std::array<std::vector<int>, 5>` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not in the way you're thinking.

Vectors have to find contiguous address space for their content.  Memory fragmentation may cause the largest contiguous block to be smaller than total free memory.  And having many vectors makes fragmentation more likely.

Comment: Isn't this practically impossible since virtual memory can extend onto the HDD?

Comment: @rm: Fragmentation isn't about physical pages, but virtual address space.  Doesn't matter how much virtual memory you have if you only have 32-bit pointers.

Answer (score 1):

No; internally, vectors hold *pointers* to the memory blocks, not the block themselves.

Answer (score 0):

`resize` won't affect the array's memory at all. The vectors have a pointer to the actual storage, so resizing affects some other memory that has nothing to do with the array's. All that will be in the array is basically just pointers pointing to possibly different lengths of memory blocks.

Furthermore, if you have something like this:

```
std::vector<int> arr [5];
```

The array's memory will be on the stack, and the vectors' memory will be on the heap. Totally different!